# Accessing element in Array, Dictionary or List using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Ive created a tool for my team which allows them to view an object visually by using the Dump() method of LinqPad. This is purely for use by the development teams to make things easier rather than having to attach a debugger which isnt always possible.

They enter the name of the object they want to Dump and the program does it in its current context.

eg. User enters `Sales.CurrentUser` and the application visualises the CurrentUser object using LinqPad's Dump() method.

```
public void VisualiseObject()
{
    object CurrentObject = this;

    string Result = GetObjectFromUser("Enter Propery or Field path eg. Sales.CurrentUser", "");

    if (Result == null)
        return;
    else if (Result != string.Empty)
    {    
        string[] Objects = Result.Split(".".ToCharArray());

        try
        {
            foreach (string objName in Objects)
            {
                CurrentObject = GetPropValue(CurrentObject, objName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        if (CurrentObject == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Object is null");
            return;
        }
    }

    CurrentObject.Dump(Result);
}

public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    object result = null;

    try
    {
        result = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            result = src.GetType().GetField(propName).GetValue(src);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = null;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Anyway im trying to think of a way to support the user supplying an index or key to a array, list or dictionary object and handle this in reflection.

The user could supply for example. An array or list `Sales.AllUsers[0]` or for dictionary `Sales.Items["Water"]`

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask a question. What did you try, what did not work or what error occurred?

Comment: You're going to have to parse this out manually, but it'll be awkward. Consider `Sales.Items["Hot.Water"], that means you can't split on `.`, you need to do it all char by char.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Dynamic Linq Expressions](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions), it allows you to do parse expressions (just be carefull with code injection).

Or you can try accessing the Get method of the array:
(given that prop is a variable of type int[])

```
var getter = array.GetType().GetMethod("Get");
var value = getter.Invoke(array, new object[] { index });
```

Haven't tested with Dictionary or Collection but should also work in the same way.